# Excel Find formula split string of names

Tags: excel, string, split, excel-formula

I'm trying to split a list of names, They in the form of:

```
Surname, Title. Firstname (Nickname)

Jonesy, Mr. Cheese (Edam)
Bukowski, Mrs. Gertrude (Gerti)
```

I need to put them into Firstname Surname

It should be easy to pick up the Firstname: Two characters after the dot of Title up to the space before the left bracket of Nickname. Only my excel formula doesn't give me what I want.

```
A1 Smith, Mr. Andrew (Andy)
A2 =MID(A1,1,Find(" ",A1)-2)
A3 =MID(A1,Find(".",A1)+2, Find("(",A1)+1)
```

Only for A3 I get:

```
Andrew (Andy)
```

Instead of just the name Andrew

I'll add the caveat that I need the formula to refer to the name cell and not an cell with temp data to be referenced (ie an interim cell)

I can't see the woods for the trees on this one. Need to call in a bigger brain.

Comment: @BruceWayne  Do any of you know why my original formula didn't work?

Comment: Yeah - it's the `...Find("(",A1)+1)` part.  With `MID()` you're starting, correctly for your purposes, after the first period. The second part of the formula asks for how many characters after the `.` do you want? Currently, you have it set to `20` (just do `=FIND("(",A1)+1)` and it resolves to `20`. So it's going 20 spaces after the `.`, and so it's getting your result. If you had `Smith, Mr. Andrew (Andy Smith Jones)`, it'd return just `Andrew (Andy Smith J`.

Comment: (That said, did any of the answers below work for you? It looks like one or two should, so feel free to mark one as the answer. If none worked, you can comment on them to let us know and we can tweak the answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data setup where headers are in row 1, with your "Complete Name" in column A starting in row 2, like so:

[image]

In cell B2 and copied down is this formula to get the first name:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+2,FIND("(",A2)-FIND(".",A2)-3)
```

In cell C2 and copied down is this formula to get the last name:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single formula to get the `Firstname Surname`:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)+1,SEARCH("(",A1)-SEARCH(".",A1)-1))&" "&MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1)-2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple I think....(Famous last words).

You had:

```
A1 = Smith, Mr. Andrew (Andy)
A2 =MID(A1,1,Find(" ",A1)-2)
A3 =MID(A1,Find(".",A1)+2, Find("(",A1)+1)
```

I replaced the A# Find "(" with " " and it worked.

```
A1 = Smith, Mr. Andrew (Andy)
A2 =MID(A1,1,Find(" ",A1)-2)
A3 =MID(A1,Find(".",A1)+2, Find(" ",A1)+1)
```

This will only work if you have a single Firstname though. A name like Bobby Joe or Billy Bob will cut off at Bobby and Billy.